# GCP Dialogflow Java-SpringBoot authentication - Application Default Credentials are not available

Tags: spring-boot, google-cloud-platform, dialogflow-es, cloud-foundry

I need to connect to GCP Dialogflow for detecting intents. I'm using SpringBoot with Java to connect to Dialogflow. This application runs in Pivotal Cloud Foundry (PCF) and I don't know how GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS environment variable can be set there.

All suggested solutions here use either `gcloud`, Google SDK or the app runs in Google Compute Engine. These solutions don't work for my architecture.

`GoogleCredentials` is always null even if it is set as suggested below -

```
GoogleCredentials.fromStream(new FileStream("creds.json"));
```

OR

```
GoogleCredentials creds = null;
try {
    creds = GoogleCredentials.fromStream(new FileInputStream("creds.json"));
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Error -

```
java.io.IOException: The Application Default Credentials are not available. They are available if running in Google Compute Engine. Otherwise, the environment variable GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS must be defined pointing to a file defining the credentials...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution to the problem after more research. The whole time I was trying to do this in my SpringBoot app. It was right there, but I didn't think much of it when I first came across it earlier.

The environment variable in PCF can be set via `cf` CLI. All I had to do was add an additional command to the pipeline and that worked perfectly -

`cf set-env APP_NAME ENV_VAR_NAME ENV_VAR_VALUE`

Sources -
https://cli.cloudfoundry.org/en-US/v6/set-env.html
https://docs.cloudfoundry.org/devguide/deploy-apps/environment-variable.html

P.S. If a new app is being pushed to PCF, please verify before running above command since APP_NAME won't be found in that case.